# How to get the data from Azure Service Bus without long polling?

Tags: azure

I am new to Azure Service Bus. I need to get the data from Service Bus. I was going through few of the blogs and found that to get the data from Service Bus I need to do long polling? Is it possible that Service Bus pushes the data to my subscriber instead of subscriber doing long polling?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

The ASB queues semantics are designed for pull model. Therefore, your clients must poll to get the data, and SDK should be abstracting much of that.
Please take a look at [Crossover Scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/messaging#crossover-scenarios) how you can stitch the event grid to push events to the consumer, using a push model.  I think that's what you're looking for.

If you provide some concrete examples why you want push than pull, I can elaborate further on the rule of thumbs on the design decision.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [Service Bus Explorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/blob/develop/media/service-bus-explorer.png). I do not know specifics of data you want to view, but it is good to know that tool anyway. It let you see a lot of insights about Service Bus resource (messages, topics, subscriptions etc.).